# NextJS wont recognise middleware.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, jsx, middleware

I have some problem in my project, some how Nextjs dont recognise my middleware !

src\middleware.ts

```
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export default async function name(req: NextRequest) {
    if (req.nextUrl.pathname === '/') {
        console.log('TRACK!')
    }
}

export const matcher = {
    matcher: ['/'],
}
```

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    matcher: ['/*'],
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Search the internent and asked chat gpt / copilot and look trough stackoverflow and other forms.

Comment: Your pages/app folder are inside src?

Comment: No it was not but now it is that worked but it  breaks my app.

can we not change that we dont use the src folder but a other folder ?

Comment: If you're not using pages/app folder inside src your middleware should be on the root of your project. From the docs `Use the file middleware.ts (or .js) in the root of your project to define Middleware. For example, at the same level as pages or app, or inside src if applicable.`

Comment: I understand but some how it is not working what you asked me that worked but this is not:

app
 -> (group)
-> middleware.ts

Comment: Your middleware.ts has to be in the same level as your pages/app folder. Can you share your project struct?

Comment: 1.Main folder
2. app folder
3. is inside app folder middleware.ts

Comment: Change your middleware to be inside main folder, same level as app folder.

Comment: there was a different middleware there is a a conflicted happening I have one for 

import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
and one for Nexth auth some how I have to combine them now.

just found out you cant have 2 middleware:

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/nested-middleware

Comment: Hmm got it. You will have to combine boths of thens inside the same one and filter the logic by the url pathname, as the documentation says.